# TYPO3 powermail front end set pid

Tags: typo3

I want to use powermail for a commenting system, including powermail and powermail frontend with typoscript on every page..
With the frond end module I would like to show only the mails of the current page.

I can set the value with

```
plugin.tx_powermail {
  settings {
    Pi2 {
      main.pid = 15
    }
  }
}
```

which works

How do I assign the current page id?

```
main.pid.data = gp:id
```

does not work.

Or is there any approach for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
main.pid.data = page:uid
```

should give you the uid of the current page.